# Why is brace-initialization not needed with array of struct?

Tags: c, curly-braces, list-initialization

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct
{
    int i;
    const char* str;
} ar[] = {
    1,"asd", //should be {1, "asd"},
    2, "qwe", //should be {2, "qwe"},
    3, "poi" //should be {3,"poi"}
};

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", ar[2].str);
}
```

Works perfectly fine, even though each element of array `ar` should enclosed in braces (I would expect that at least). Why is this possible?

Comment: Backwards compatibility.  Because pre-standard C did it that way, and standard C had to work with pre-standard source whenever possible.

Comment: Never knew that. Great find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[6.7.9 Initialization/20](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p20) states how such struct elements are initialized:

> [..] If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins
> with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its
> matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the
> subaggregate or the contained union. Otherwise, **only enough
> initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or
> members of the subaggregate or the first member of the contained
> union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next
> element or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate
> or contained union is a part.**

(*emphasis mine*)

So it's valid. And thus

```
ar[] = {
    1,"asd",
    2, "qwe",
    3, "poi"
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
 ar[] = {
    {1,"asd"},
    {2, "qwe"},
    {3, "poi"}
};
```

and `ar` contains 3 elements.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for the very simple reason that the standard allows it.

So why does the standard allow it? Well, I don't know if there's any rationale behind this. The most likely reason is that it's simply because of backwards compatibility. The C language is literary full of such things.

However, it is considered bad style. So avoid it. And if you compile with warnings enabled, which you **shall** do, you get this warning:

```
warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
    7 | } ar[] = {
      |          ^
    8 |     1,"asd", //should be {1, "asd"},
      |     {      }
    9 |     2, "qwe", //should be {2, "qwe"},
      |     {       }
   10 |     3, "poi" //should be {3,"poi"}
      |     {
   11 | };
      | }
```

And the philosophy behind C is very different compared to many other languages. One could argue that even if it's bad style to omit the braces, there is not really a reason to forbid omitting them. For instance, it does not cause any ambiguity.