# List initialization of array of structs without internal braces

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Vertex {
    float x,y,z,u,v;
};

int main()
{
    struct Vertex v[2] = { 1,2,3,4,5,
                        6,7,8,9,10};
    
    printf("%f", v[1].x);
}
```

When compiled by GCC, this program prints `6.000000`.

Is this to be expected or is it relying on undefined behavior?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799943/why-is-brace-initialization-not-needed-with-array-of-struct

Comment: With proper compiler warnings, this code will throw a warning `-Wmissing-braces`. When treating warnings as errors, this code does not compile. This won't be a problem with `struct Vertex v[2] = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10} };`